# How to use nginx to redirect one page request to a different page

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect `http://example.com/balcony-covers/` to
`http://example.com/balcony-screens/` permanently. How can I do this in nginx.

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your nginx.conf file.

Put

```
location /balcony-covers/ {
    return 301 $scheme://$host/balcony-screens/;
}
```

in your `server` block